# After `brew install mysql` mysqld fails to start, complaining about unknown option "--skip-locking". How do I fix this?

Tags: mysql

Lots of details here...

```
OS: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
$ brew --version
Homebrew 1.5.12
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision af232; last commit 2018-03-27)
```

I could no longer connect to my local mysql, so I reinstalled with brew, following instructions at https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks including restarting after uninstalling mysql.

Running mysql_install_db is successful:

```
2018-03-27 10:17:01 [WARNING] mysql_install_db is deprecated. Please consider switching to mysqld --initialize
2018-03-27 10:17:01 [NOTE]    Creating data directory /usr/local/var/mysql
2018-03-27 10:17:01 [NOTE]    Generating random password to /Users/me/.mysql_secret...done.
2018-03-27 10:17:01 [NOTE]    Executing /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld --bootstrap --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --lc-messages-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/share/mysql --lc-messages=en_US --basedir=/usr/local/opt/mysql
2018-03-27 10:17:03 [NOTE]    Creating system tables...done.
2018-03-27 10:17:03 [NOTE]    Filling system tables with data...done.
2018-03-27 10:17:04 [NOTE]    Filling help table with data...done.
2018-03-27 10:17:04 [NOTE]    Creating user for internal session service...done.
2018-03-27 10:17:04 [NOTE]    Creating default user root@localhost
2018-03-27 10:17:04 [NOTE]    Creating default proxy root@localhost
2018-03-27 10:17:04 [NOTE]    Creating sys schema
2018-03-27 10:17:06 [NOTE]    done.
2018-03-27 10:17:07 [WARNING] The bootstrap log isn't empty:
2018-03-27 10:17:07 [WARNING] 2018-03-27T17:17:01.939957Z 0 [Warning] --bootstrap is deprecated. Please consider using --initialize instead
```

When I try running `mysql.server start` I get this error message on the command line:

... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/myhostname.pid).

And here's the error in `/usr/local/var/mysql/myhostname.err`:

```
2018-03-27T17:30:40.451904Z 0 [ERROR] unknown option '--skip-locking'
```

There is no `/etc/my.cnf` file.

Here's what I do see from `/usr/local`:

```
find Cellar/mysql/ var/mysql -name my.cnf
Cellar/mysql//5.7.21/.bottle/etc/my.cnf

$ cat Cellar/mysql//5.7.21/.bottle/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And I also added `set -x` to `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld_safe` and here's the command-line it uses to launch:

```
nohup /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld \
    --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21 \
    --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql \
    --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/lib/plugin \
    --log-error=Erics-MacBook-Pro-601.err \
    --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/Erics-MacBook-Pro-601.pid \
    --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock \
    --port=3306
```

So where is the `--skip-locking` option getting injected? Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: Is the `skip locking` in the `my.cnf` enabled?   You might want to try commenting out the `skip locking` in the `my.cnf` and then see if it'll run.  --  Usually located *here* -- But it depends on your installation  --> `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Also a note -- `skip locking` has been deprecated since version 5.5  .. So if it *is* in your `my.cnf` (since you are 5.7) It **will** fail ..

Comment: Thx zak. I was searching in the server my.cnf's, but found the problem in my own ~/.my.cnf.

Answer (score 1):

Found it in ~/.my.cnf

[Extra text added to appease stackoverflow]